# Dealing with Caliburn Micro's static IoC

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, prism, caliburn.micro

I am required to host multiple modules (all done using Caliburn Micro) inside a Prism based container. Within the container, multiple view from the same module can be created (Example: Scientific and Financial Calculator can be created from the Calculator module).

I am using Unity for DI and therefore has overriden the Caliburn Micro's bootstrapper in all modules to resolve from the unity container.

As [CM's IoC](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/IoC.cs) class is a static class, the last module registering it's dependencies overwrites the ([previous one](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Caliburn.Micro.Silverlight/Bootstrapper.cs)) - see the line IoC.GetInstance = GetInstance.

I quite like the idea that Sniffer suggested, but each module creates its own child container so it would not applicable in my scenario.

Comment: I don't see the exact problem, You are trying multiple instances of the Calculator module so all `GetInstance()` function registrations should be the same so why you don't want the override to happen ? I hope you can explain your question more clearly. Thank you.

Comment: You are correct, sorry I missed the part, in my scenario the container would include multiple instances of different modules (say calendar, calculator, notepad etc) that all uses CM. As IoC is static if notepad module is loaded at the end, then it would overwrite calendard and calculator registrations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will suggest a solution that I think would work. By default CM assigns `IoC.GetInstance()` and all other `Func<>` delegates in the `BootstrapperBase` simply like this:

```
IoC.GetInstance = this.GetInstance
```

Where `this.GetInstance` is simply a method in `BootstrapperBase` that is virtual and empty so you can override it in your own derived bootstrapper.

My attempted solution: Store a reference to what is already registered with `IoC.GetInstance` and call it in your new `GetInstance` override, and do this for the other two static `Func<>`'s of `IoC`.

Inthe constructor or `Configure()` method of your bootstrappers, provide hooks for those static `Func<>` delegates in `IoC` that wrap each other, something like this:

```
public class CalculatorBootstrapper : BootstrapperBase {

    private Func<Type, string, object> _previousGet;     

    public override void Configure() {
        _previousGet = IoC.GetInstance; // store reference to whatever was stored previously
        IoC.GetInstance = this.GetInstance;
    }

    public override Object GetInstance(Type type, string key) {
        var result = null;
        if (_previousGet != null)
            result = _previousGet(type, key);
        if (result == null) {
            // Try to use the local container here

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a bit hacky but I like it :)

Comment: @Charleh Thank you. I know it is a bit hacky and I hope it works, as you can see his situation is not a pretty common one and a little bit weird so the solution is something like that too :).

Comment: The idea is not bad, Thanks. This would work for most cases, we can iterate over chain of Previously-Registered-Containers to resolve otherwise use local container. But this would not work when module creates child containers, example host scientific and financial calculator (same module), both calculator would have registrations derived from parent container, but they may also have private registrations (via child container example IFormatNumber), in this case the resolution would not work. Query for IFormatNumber would always resolve from previous container if initiated from 2nd calculator.

Comment: @RohitSharma Can you show some code or some outline of how those two calculators in the same module are using the child containers ?

Comment: Hi Sniffer, here is snippet that shows how the child containers are initialized http://snipt.org/AgjL0, essentially every time we create a view the lambda gets called (this is where the child container is initialized and passed to bootstrapper), as multiple view would register their own INumberFormatProvider, the resolution would be ambigious.

Comment: Sniffer: On second thoughts I think your approach is workable. I will make a sample later this week and will come back to you. Thanks :)